# Sort an array by textual date column in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Something easy I think.

I have a two dimensional list (array) of mixed date, text and numeric data sourced from a CSV. I want to be able to sort the rows by the value in a single column, which in this case is a date in text format. For example:

`{{1/12/2008, Bob, 123},
  {28/06/2007, Alice, 456},
  {19/08/2009, Charlie, 789}}`

I'd like to sort the rows in the list by the date (so that comes out in the order Alice, Bob, Charlie.)

So far I have thought that I might want to map `DateList` across my date column and prepend the year, month and day to the list, so it becomes:

`{{2008, 12, 1, Bob, 123}, {2007, 6, 28, Alice, 456}}`

Then I'm left having to do three sorts instead of one, and needing to break the array up by year. That didn't seem right and now I'm stuck. I know this ought to be simple but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks,

Tim

Comment: Not sure if this question will get looked at again.... I have almost the same question, but my array has dates in this form,  "2024-04-02 14:00",  in column 3.   If anyone could help with modifying this solution to work with sorting dates in that format in column 3, that would help me out  a lot....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps this ...

```
l = {{"1/12/2008", Bob, 123}, {"28/06/2007", Alice, 456}, 
     {"19/08/2009", Charlie, 789}}

SortBy[l, AbsoluteTime[{#[[1]], {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}] &]
```

gives

```
{{"28/06/2007", Alice,   456}, 
 {"1/12/2008",  Bob,     123}, 
 {"19/08/2009", Charlie, 789}}
```

HTH

**Edit**

Note that **Sort[ ]** compares using **OrderedQ[ ]**, and so it can compare lists. (Greater[ ], for example, can't).

So, the following code also works:

```
Sort@(Flatten@{DateList[{#[[1]],{"Day","Month","Year"}}], #[[2]], #[[3]]} & /@ l)
```

or perhaps more elegant:

```
Sort@(l/.{x_String, y__} :> Flatten@{DateList[{x, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}], y})
```

Comment: Legend. Thanks belisarius, that worked perfectly. I spent hours trawling through the docs and never saw a reference to SortBy, or AbsoluteTime!

Comment: +1, never heard of `SortBy` before.  I've always used `Sort`, plus custom sorting functions.

Comment: I too like this solution (and I too had not heard of AbsoluteTime). A slight variation is that DateList (which I had been playing around with) will also work, as in: SortBy[l,DateList[{#[[1]],{"Day","Month","Year"}}]&]//TableForm

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to belisarius' second method:

```
lst = {{"1/12/2008", Bob, 123},
       {"28/06/2007", Alice, 456}, 
       {"19/08/2009", Charlie, 789}};

lst = {DateList@{#, {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}, ##2} & @@@ lst;

Sort@lst
```